# Python 2/3 subprocess.Popen and non ascii characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to execute commands that are passed as strings via subprocess.Popen call, I want to know how to do it in the most platform and python 3/2 agnostic way. Here is an example:

```
# content of test.py
import subprocess

with open('test.cmd', 'rb') as f:
    cmd = f.read().decode('UTF-8')

print(cmd)

pro = subprocess.Popen('bash',
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = pro.communicate(cmd)

pro.wait()
print(out)
print(err)
```

I'm emulating the passing of string with non-ascii characters by reading it from file, here is the content of test.cmd file:

```
echo АБВГ
```

The string reads well, and the output of print(cmd) statement is correct. How ever when I try to pass cmd to communicate function it fails. In python 2 it says that 'ascii' codec can't encode characters, so it seems it tries to convert it to unicode from str and it thinks that the str has only latin1 characters. How should I get the str object encoded in the right way? In python 3 the communicate function expects bytes as input, but what encoding should be used?

Comment: If you do not decode the cmd to utf-8, what happens then?

Comment: If I don't decode the cmd after reading it it does work indeed, but only on OS that uses UTF-8 as the default console encoding. But I'm reading command and decoding it to demonstrate the situation exactly. In fact I'm getting commands as str objects on both python 2 and 3. I wanted to find a way to do it in that exact case.

Answer (score 2):

> In python 2 it says that 'ascii' codec can't encode characters, so it seems it tries to convert it to unicode

It tries to encode unicode to str. Try to encode it explicitly `pro.communicate(cmd.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: It seems to work, but how can I make sure that the current operating system uses UTF-8 for encoding? How can I get the system's bash encoding for example?

Comment: Your file maybe encoded any encode, it's not depending of OS.
If you want to find out which encoding uses certain file you can use python package http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Not the file, the bash process.

Comment: echo $LC_CTYPE; echo $LC_ALL. Bash stores strings as byte strings, and performs operations according to the current LC_CTYPE setting. You can set the LC_CTYPE or LC_ALL variable to your desired locale.

Comment: sys.getdefaultencoding()